# Return Primary Key after saving to a model in Django

Tags: python, django, return

I've seen the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#auto-incrementing-primary-keys) and several similar stack Overflow posts, but after saving my form I'm still unable to return the ID/PK of that new model. It keeps telling me `'ProposalForm' object has no attribute 'id'`
**How can I return the ID right after saving?**

Here's the View:

```
def proposal_create_view2(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ProposalForm(data=request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                response = {}
                response['proposalID'] = form.id
                return response
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

my_saved_model = my_model_form.save()

print my_saved_model.pk

**Edit:**

```
def proposal_create_view2(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProposalForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            mysaved_model = form.save()
            response = {}
            response['proposalID'] = mysaved_model.id #or .pk
            return render(request , 'my_template_file.html' , response) 

            #return response statement is NOT valid as you need to return an HttpResponse not a dict
```

Review [Django Docs on HttpResponses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects)

Comment: I know I'm just an idiot here. but I guess I don't know what my code would be for my_saved_model. I'm attempting to retrive the new proposal object with `response['proposalID'] = Proposal.objects.get(user=request.user, create_date=datetime.datetime.now())
            return response`  But that's not working either. What's the actual code I would use in my example?

Comment: @MichaelRomrell I updated the answer , hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Thank you SO Much! I'm just learning Django so I appreciate your patience. I ended up further modifying your return statement to `return HttpResponse(mysaved_model.id)` since I didn't want the template to load again. You're Awesome Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The return value from `ModelForm.save()` is the new model. Take the PK from that instead.

Comment: I'm pretty new at Django so I don't fully understand. could you elaborate? Specifically how would I take it from the new model?

Comment: The same way you're currently trying to take it from the form. Except from the model returned by the method.